# How set selected in a datalist HTML PHP

Tags: php, html

Greetings I would like to know if there is a way to set a selected value in a datalist. I would like something like this

```
<input list="cars" class="form-control" name="caBrands" style="width:300px;">
  <datalist id="cars"  >
     <option selected="selected" value="BMW">
     <option value="Toyota">
     <option value="Mitsubishi">
  </datalist>
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The datalist is just an auto-complete list to be used with a textual input element. If you want to pre-set a value, just set the value of the input:

```html
 <input list="cars" value="BMW" class="form-control" name="caBrands" style="width:300px;">
 <datalist id="cars">
 <option value="BMW">
 <option value="Toyota">
 <option value="Mitsubishi">
 </datalist>
```

If you want to always select a value from a list, you can use a select element. This allows marking one option as selected, but it doesn't allow freeform input:

```html
<select class="form-control" name="caBrands" style="width:300px;">
 <option selected value="BMW">BMW</option>
 <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
 <option value="Mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you been searching these for days. I thought datalist is like a drop down so i keep on doing the "selected" function. Thanks man.

Comment: With the first solution though, you end up with only BMW in the list if you expand it. At least on Chrome 77 and firefox 70.

Comment: @LukeSkywalker That's because it's an auto-complete list providing incremental search. In this case the  list is already filtered, because the value BMW is pre-filled. If you leave value empty (or if you backspace the current value), you'll see the other possibilities show up. This works the same as in the [DataList example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist#Examples). The first time you can select all the options, but as soon as one is selected, you will see only that option in the drop down, until your clear the value again.

Answer (score -1):

Set defaultValue on input tag. For example -

```
<input list="browsers" defaultValue="Bravo" class="form-control" name="browserList" style="width:300px;">
 <datalist id="browsers">
   <option value="Bravo">
   <option value="Opera">
   <option value="Edge">
 </datalist>
```